# checking for the file type(.txt,jpg,etc) and size before uploading

Tags: asp.net

i am trying to uplaod the file . before that i need  to check  for the  file type  and  size  before  saving  into the  specified  folder.
 i need   allow  user  only  upload .jpg, .bmp, .swf,.png,.tiff,
 no other  fiel  like .txt,  pdf, .doc  and   need  to check file  size  is  always less   than  1 MB. can we  do this in javascript  or c#  coding

2: and  before  saving the  file  i need  to  check  if  there  is any file  with a  same  name in  the  folder  if it is there   than  alret the  user telling  a  file  name  exits
and   should  rename the   file

any solution on this   would be  great
  thank  you

Answer (score 2):

As for checking the file size and extension prior to uploading, you'll need to use some form of client side control for such.  I'd recommend something like http://swfupload.org/.

As for checking to see if the same file name exists on the server prior, you'll need to use one of the pre-upload events from such a component to make an ajax call to the server to verify such.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regular expression to check file type

```
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rexpImageE" Display="Dynamic" runat="server"
 ControlToValidate="fup1" ErrorMessage="Only .gif, .jpg, .jpeg, .png, .tiff"
 ValidationExpression="(.*\.([Gg][Ii][Ff])|.*\.([Jj][Pp][Gg])|.*\.([Bb][Mm][Pp])|.*\.([pP][nN][gG])|.*\.([tT][iI][iI][fF])$)"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
```

and you can check file size on server side like

```
 if (fup1.PostedFile.ContentLength > lengthInBytes)
    {
        //your message
        return;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can only check filename and size after the file is sent to the server in C#.

You can use the [`FileName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.fileupload.filename.aspx) property to check the name.  To get the file's extension, you can write `Path.GetExtension(upload.FileName)`.  Note that the fact that the file's extension is `jpg` doesn't mean that it's actually a JPEG image.

To check whether the file already exists, write `File.Exists(Path.Combine(@"Your folder", upload.FileName))`

To get the size in bytes, check `upload.PostedFile.ContentLength`.

Comment: Down voted : Clearly the size is available in the form handler in the PostedFile.ContentLength.  Checking after having saved the file to your server is plan silly

Comment: @Andrew: I was trying to say that you can't do it in Javascript.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the correct way to do this on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479405.aspx).

Here's a quick snippet which checks the file type:

```
if (bannerImageUpload.HasFile)
{
    if (bannerFileExt == ".jpg")
    {
        Stream bannerFileStream = bannerImageUpload.PostedFile.InputStream;
        bannerFileData = new byte[bannerImageUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength];
        bannerFileStream.Read(bannerFileData, 0, 
            bannerImageUpload.PostedFile.ContentLength);
    }
}
```

It's probably easier to use a RegularExpressionValidator to do this on the client. Note the use of the ContentLength property. Use File.Exists to check directory folder for any existing file with same name as explained by SLaks :-)